# How do I GetSessionToken from AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient created with temporary saml credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-sts

Here's what I'm trying to do-

```
var role = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

role.AssumeRole(new AssumeRoleRequest
{
    DurationSeconds = 3600,
    RoleArn = rolearn,
    RoleSessionName = sessionname
});

GetSessionTokenResponse sessionTokenResponse = role.GetSessionToken(new GetSessionTokenRequest
{
    DurationSeconds = 7200
});
```

Now my "role" is created with temporary credentials I obtained with saml. And it seems that since GetSessionToken provides you with temporary credentials, it needs "role" to be created with long term credentials. I can't seem to find a workaround for this.

Essentially, I'm trying to create an AmazonS3Client with assumed IAM role that has certain permissions. Here's what I plan to do if I manage to GetSessionToken-

```
var newcreds = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials;
var sessionCredentials = new SessionAWSCredentials(newcreds.AccessKeyId, newcreds.SecretAccessKey, newcreds.SessionToken);
AmazonS3Client newclient = new AmazonS3Client(sessionCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call GetSessionToken using credentials returned by AssumeRoleWithSAML. From AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithSAML.html):

> The temporary security credentials created by AssumeRoleWithSAML can
>   be used to make API calls to any AWS service with the following
>   exception: you cannot call the STS service's GetFederationToken or
>   GetSessionToken API operations.